# Multer is undefined in express app while testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs, multer

I am using jest to test my express app made with TS which uses multer to upload files. But my test ends with error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'diskStorage')"`.
The app works fine, the error is only when I test.

My error happens in -

```
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "images/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        cb(
            null,
            (
                file.fieldname +
                "-" +
                uniqueSuffix +
                "-" +
                file.originalname
            ).replace(/ /g, "_")
        );
    },
});

function filter(req: object, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: Function) {
    cb(null, file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || file.mimetype === "image/jpeg");
}

const postStorage = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: filter,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024, // max size in bytes
    },
});

export default postStorage;
```

Then I am using it in my routes -

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAll);
router.post(
    "/",
    postStorage.fields([
        { name: "main_image", maxCount: 1 },
        { name: "additional_images", maxCount: 5 },
    ]),
    RequestValidator(PostSchema, "body"),
    insert
);

export default router;
```

My jest code is -

```
describe("do ", () => {
    describe("dodo", () => {
        it("dododo", async () => {
            await supertest(app).get("/").expect(200);
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you doing here is basically the integration testing which means that you've actually making the request and actually storing the data in db right ??

**In Case i'm right**

**Then the error is pretty much expected**

because you're actually making the request to that endpoint,but aren't passig the data to that endPoint or the image url if you wanna say.

**In Case i'm wrong**

let's say you're doing the **unit testing** which's differet then you'd have to use the mock data  to create the same behaviour.

[Here's the example how to use multer for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317652/how-to-write-unit-test-case-for-uploadfiles-method-using-jest)

Comment: I was trying to do unit testing. Can you give me any direction on this? I want to test the API which takes formdata as POST, while ignoring the multer part.

Comment: For the unit test you don't actually have to make the request use the mock data